# Rewrite rules for mod_rewrite to mimic virtual directories

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am running a multi-client application without subdomains. I need to stick to using *virtual subfolders*:

The application itself is located at:
`example.com/`

I need the following address pattern to map to the above address:

`example.com/any-valid-string/*` -> `example.com/*` (*without redirect*)

For example:

`example.com/any-valid-string/assets/css/style.css`

actually resolves physically to

`example.com/assets/css/style.css`

I am working now with a hard-coded client name, for example called "sample" this does the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^sample/?(.*)$ $1 [QSA,NS,L]
```

I need the "sample" part also dynamic, I tried the following but without success:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?(.*)$ $2 [QSA,NS,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^[^/]+(/.*)?$ /$1 [NS,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! It is working except for the following case, when I request for example example.com/any-valid-string without the trailing slash it doest load the assets.

Comment: Do you have some other rules also? When I opened `http://localhost/any-valid-string` it opened `http://localhost/` for me (without changing the URL in the browser).